# Can't see typescript file in Chrome browser using web pack

Tags: angular, browser, typescript, asp.net-core, webpack

We create ***Asp.net core*** application with ***Angularjs2***. We use webpack for control *.ts* file. The file is as follow:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = [
{
entry: {
  core: './node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
  zone: './node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
  reflect: './node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
  system: './node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
},
output: {
  filename: './wwwroot/js/[name].js'
},
target: 'web',
node: {
  fs: "empty"
}
},
{
entry: {
  app: './wwwroot/app/main.ts'
},
output: {
  filename: './wwwroot/app/bundle.js'
},
devtool: 'source-map',
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
},
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
  ]
}}];
```

After this configuration I see only few *.ts* files in browser:

[image]

But actually we have more files:

[image]

What is wrong in *webpack.config*?

Comment: Try open the webpack folder instead of wwwroot/app. There you should see all files provided by webpack.

Comment: @jmachnik, I add image, wwwroot/app is in webpack

Comment: http://imgur.com/sa7DHty what's inside this folder in your chrome dev tools?

Comment: @jmachnik, I update first image.